# What are the Blackjack rules used in Atlantic City casinos?

Tags: house-rules, blackjack, betting

I understand that Blackjack in Atlantic City casinos is regulated by the state and that they determine the rules of Blackjack that all the casinos must adhere to.

Specifically, I would like to know:

- Is the dealer required to stand on a soft 17?
- How many decks are used?
- Is the shoe normally played to the last card or is it shuffled before being empty?
- How many times can you split?
- Can you double down after splitting?
- Can you double down after splitting Aces?
- Can a split Ace be dealt more than one card?
- Does a split Ace and ten value card count as Blackjack or 21?
- If the dealer has Blackjack and you have 21 (but not Blackjack) do you lose the hand?
- What is the payout for Blackjack?
- Is insurance offered? How much does it cost?
- Is late or early surrender offered?
- What is the minimum bet per hand at the major Atlantic City casinos?
- By how much can you increase or decrease your bet between hands?

Comment: The minimum bet depends on the table you play at. I haven't been to Atlantic City, but every casino I have been in has different tables with different minimums. The lowest I've seen at the big ones is $10

Answer (score 1):

[Random article from Google](http://blackjack-authority.com/game-guide/atlantic-city.html)

- Stand on soft 17
- Eight decks
- No mention of shoe emptying rules
- Splitting up to 3 times (total of 4 hands)
- Double down after splitting is allowed
- Not explicitly mentioned but unlikely due to one card after split Ace
- One card each after splitting an ace (and no resplit)
- Ace and ten after split is 21
- The dealer does check for Blackjack, so 21 never occurs vs Blackjack
- Blackjack pays 3 to 2
- Insurance is allowed and pays 2 to 1, typically insurance is up to half your original bet in this case (not explicitly mentioned)
- Late surrender is allowed
- No mention of minimum bet
- No mention of betting rules